# how to use SQL [charlist] Wildcard . help me the code doesn't working in mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, wildcard

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '[bsp]%';

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: We can't help if you don't tell us what happens. What is the detail of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has different wildcards than those documented on that website:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

For this problem you probably want to use the [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operator:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City REGEXP '^[bsp].*';
```